# How are two registers are enough to simulate a Turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models

The paper *[A universal cellular automaton in the hyperbolic plane](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397502006606)* says:

> Our simulation consists in simulating the execution of a register machine. It is known that **two registers are enough to simulate a Turing machine**, see [10], and so, by such a simulation, we shall obtain a universal computation.

It links to [10] which is *[Computation: Finite and Infinite Machines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131655639)*, a $200 book from Minsky with no reasonable/free version seemingly available on the web, so no easy access.

How are two registers enough to simulate a Turing machine? How do we know that? What is the sketch laid out in the Minsky book that explains how this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reduction is [sketched on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_machine#Two-counter_machines_are_Turing_equivalent_(with_a_caveat)).